# Using jQuery's .live/.bind to affect input created by a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, for-loop, delegation

I have two arrays, one with input names, and one with the value to give each input. There are 7 inputs, so I made a loop to fill out each input with it's value, then make it so that the text will disappear when that input is focused, and restore the original value text if nothing was typed. Is this possible to do through a loop with jQuery? It seems to me .live and .bind won't work for this purpose. Will I have to hardcore in each input event focus&blur event?

```
for (var i=0;i<7;i++) {

    $('#user_' + input_names[i]).attr('value', default_values[i]);

    $('#user_' + input_names[i]).live("blur", function(){
        if(this.value == '')this.value=default_values[i];
    });

    $('#user_' + input_names[i]).live("focus", function(){
        if(this.value == default_values[i])this.value='';
    });

}
```

---

Update here, releasing the arrays as Eric requested:

```
var input_names = ['username', 'password'];
var default_values = ['Username', 'Password'];

for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {    
    $('#user_' + input_names[i]).attr('value', default_values[i]);

    $('#user_' + input_names[i]).blur(function(){
        if(this.value == '')this.value=default_values[i];
    });

    $('#user_' + input_names[i]).focus(function(){
        if(this.value == default_values[i])this.value='';
    });
}
```

Comment: Are the `#user_...` elements dynamically generated? Can we see the code that generates them?

Comment: The #user_ is the prefix for the input names. They go like this: #user_username, #user_... etc. Not integers.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you show us the code that generates them, things can be simplified greatly. Why can't you attach the handlers when you generate them?

Comment: Sorry, so the `inputs` *aren't* created by the for loop, just the event bindings? That was how I read the title.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're looking for the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute. Just change your HTML to this:

```
<input id="user_username" placeholder="Username" />
<input id="user_password" placeholder="Password" />
```

If you want backwards compatibility, [there's a jQuery plugin for that](https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder). With the plugin referenced, just do this:

```
$('input[placeholder]').placeholder();
```

---

As for what's wrong with your initial code, I suspect there's a closure problem, and `i` is retaining the value of 7. You'd do better to rewrite it like this:

```
var inputDefaults = {username: 'Username', password: 'Password'};

$.each(inputDefaults, function(field, defaultValue) {
    $('#user_' + field)
        .attr('value', defaultValue);
        .blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '')
                $(this).val(defaultValue);
        })
        .focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == defaultValue)
                $(this).val('');
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, nice suggestion. However, since HTML5 isn't too compitable with older browsers I still think I need to use jQuery. Keep 'em coming.

Comment: @Melanie: That's what the jQuery plugin is for!

Comment: @Melanie: Updated. I **strongly** suggest you show us the code that generates these inputs. And where `default_values` comes from. There's a much better solution than this one if I have those.